# Copy Active Directory attribute to another attribute and modify it

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I managed to copy an Attribute to another ("physicalDeliveryOfficeName" to "l"):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter '(sAMAccountName -eq "MyUserName")' -Properties l, physicalDeliveryOfficeName | ForEach-Object {Set-ADObject -Identity $_.DistinguishedName ` -Replace @{l=$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName)}}
```

But how can I manipulate the object before inserting it into the new attribute.

Lets say:
physicalDeliveryOfficeName: "1234 City"

Now I want to remove the numbers and spaces before inserting it into the new attribute "l".

Comment: You would do that in your subexpression `$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -replace '^\d+\s+')`. Is there something you tried that was not working?

Comment: I tried to manipulate it in an other for loop, but I knew that there has to be an easier way to do this. Yours works like a charm :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply would do that in your subexpression of your calculated property

```
$($_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -replace '^\d+\s+')
```

That regex string will replace all leading digits (assuming there are not other characters at the start of the string) and all whitespace that follows it.